# Are there any known issues with using database triggers for reacting to a WMX Job status change?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, oracle-spatial, arcgis-workflow-manager

I'm looking to notify another system when a WMX job (*of particular job type*) has been closed.  And I know this will be a call to an Oracle package. I'm considering a database trigger because it seems to be the most straightforward approach, but cautious because I'm not finding a lot of chatter in the forums.  **Are there any "gotchas" (WMX  or Oracle) to look out for with this approach?**

Notes:

- Workflow Manager for ArcGIS 10.0
- Oracle 11g
- Want to avoid using custom notifiers and/or python scripts on client
  workstations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been running a trigger on the `JTX_JOBS` table for a few weeks (in a development environment).

Thus far, the only issue was an exception thrown when subsequent procedures query the the JTX_JOBS table:
`ORA-04091: table XXXX is mutating, trigger/function may not see it`

Initial, poor trigger design on my part and easily fixed by updating stored procedures to receive additional values from the `:NEW` pseudo-record.